# Show a ring has only one prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $R = \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^p-1)$. I want to show that $(x-1,p)/(x^p-1)$ is the unique prime ideal of $R$. Indeed, consider the surjective homomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(x) \mapsto f(1)  (\text{mod } p)$, we have $\ker(\varphi) = (x-1,p)$. By the first and the third isomorphism theorems, $(x-1,p)/(x^p-1)$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, and hence prime. However, I don't know how to show uniqueness. The hint says $(x-1)^p \equiv 0 (\text{mod $p$})$ in $R$, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: The title of your question is a bit misleading, of course, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$.

You've shown that the ideal $(x-1,p)$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, hence to show that $P$ is unique, it suffices to show that $x-1\in P$ and $p\in P$.

If a product of finitely many elements of $R$ yields an element of $P$, then since $P$ is a prime ideal, it follows that at least one of the factors must be an element of $P$.

Since $p^n=0$ in $R$, we have $p^n\in P$, hence $p\in P$.

It remains to show $x-1\in P$.

Since $x^p-1=0$ in $R$, we have $x^p-1\in P$.

Applying the hint, since $p\in P$ and $x^p-1\in P$, the congruence
$$
(x-1)^p\equiv x^p-1\;(\text{mod}\;p)
$$
implies $(x-1)^p\in P$, hence $x-1\in P$.